# Nyquist theorem in matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, sampling, adc

I'm trying to make some small scripts in matlab, so I can hear both the analog and digital sine waves, but I’m confused and with 2 problems

1. In the analog code the idea is to be able to change *Tm* that is the sampling period, by changing *Tm* so I can choose whatever samples the user wants. However I'm stuck with the stem function, since I haven't been able to change the sample rate in the *stem()* function
2. In the digital code, I’m trying to make digital sound code come out from the speakers, and I did however, I’m not even sure the sound is actually digital, since when using *N=2^1* the sound can be hear at really good quality, with a little noise, (when it’s supposed to play that way only at 8 bits)
   Hopefully someone here can lend me a hand.

-------------------- FOR THE ANALOGIC SOUND

```
clf
t=0:1:17.7
y=sin(2*pi*0.06*t)          %// l von Vp de 2.5v

plot(t,y)                   %// Entry signal
hold on
plot(t,y,'ko')              %// Output graph 
stem(t,y)
hold off

n=[0:1:10000]               %// Duration of tone

ftono=440                   %// sound frequency
fm=8000                     %// frecuency sample rate 
Tm=1/fm                     %// sampling period 

A=1                  

x=A*sin(2*pi*ftono*Tm*n)    %// Sin wave using sam,pling period 

sound(x,fm)                 %// Analogic sound
```

-------------------- FOR THE DIGITAL SOUND (change N from 2^1 to 2^16)

```
     clf
t = 0:1:1600                  

fm = 1000           
Tm=1/fm

ftono = 440           

N=2^2

senial = sin(2*pi*t*ftono*Tm)

y = round(senial*N)/N

plot(round(sin(2*pi*t/1000)*N)/N)

sound(round(sin(2*pi*t*ftono*Tm)*N)/N, 1000)
```

Comment: Your problem statement has significantly changed since I made my answer. You've added an entirely different problem which I haven't addressed. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: yeah sorry about that

Comment: You need to define that you mean by "analog" and "digital". All your signals are of course discrete-time, but are transformed by `soundsc`into a continuous-time sound wave in the speakers. Aside from that, it seems that by "digital" you mean 1) quantized y-axis and 2) [zero-order hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold) in the x axis. Anyway: what's your question exactly?

Comment: I fail in spotting the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of you should understand that both of your snippets result in digital sound. This is not a result of your code. Since you reproduce sound from digital information, the sound is "digital". Thus, if both of your sounds have the same sampling frequency then both will be heard the same.

Judging from your question's subject, you should be trying to reproduce the aliasing effect caused by insufficient sampling frequencies or you should be trying to reproduce quantization noise caused by small sample word length.

The first of my assumptions is based on the sampling frequency and the second on the "8 bits" part of your answer.

You can demo both of these functionalities in the code below.

```
function adsoundtest(dur, freq, nbits, amp, fs)
%Reproduce a simulated analogue sound and a digital one
% ADSOUNTEST(DUR, FREQ, NBITS, AMP, FS)
% Duration (dur) is in seconds, freq is the signal's
% frequency in Hz, nbits is the number of bits for
% sample length, amp is the amplification of the sine
% wave (max 1) and fs is the sampling frequency in Hz.

    fs_analogue = 100 * freq;

    if nargin < 5
        if nargin < 4
            if nargin < 3
                if nargin < 2
                    error('ERROR:ADSOUNDTEST', 'Too few input arguments');
                end
                nbits = 16;
            end
            amp = 1;
        end
        fs = freq * 3;
    end

    fs_digital = fs;

    t_analogue = 0:1/fs_analogue:(dur - 1/fs_analogue);
    t_digital = 0:1/fs_digital:(dur - 1/fs_digital);

    w = 2 * pi * freq;

    x_analogue = amp .* sin(w .* t_analogue);
    x_digital = amp .* sin(w .* t_digital);

    try 
        ymax = intmax(['int' num2str(nbits)]);
        ymin = intmin(['int' num2str(nbits)]);
    catch me
        disp 'Number of bits not supported. Try 64, 32, 16 and 8';
        rethrow(me)
    end

    x_digital = round(mapminmax(x_digital, double(ymin), double(ymax)));

    sound(x_analogue, fs_analogue);
    disp('Press enter to continue')
    pause;
    sound(x_digital, fs_digital);
end
```

Comment: im having problems with that, code, to input the adsound test values, do i need to add a nother line with each value or enable the % ADSOUNTEST(DUR, FREQ, NBITS, AMP, FS) line?, its just a matter of briefly explaining how to input the values

Comment: The line that you refer to is just to show the usage of the function.